# Programmatically scrolling to a component in Vaadin application

Tags: java, scroll, vaadin

If I wanted to scroll to a newly generated component after some work is done/outputted, how would I do that via Java? Or would I need to introduce additional functions with JS/CSS files into the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});", component));
```

Here component would just be the name of the target component, and the behavior of the scrolling would be smooth. There is also "auto" for the behavior but I prefer the former.